# Question deleted because moderator thinks it looks like a spam and it is unacceptable

Tags: discussion, support

I just asked [question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/72037/is-dailymotion-cloud-expensive-compared-to-others) about pricing of DMCLOUD.net a cloud host provider; and it got deleted by a moderator within a second for the reason that it is a spam and it is unnacceptable:

> This looks like spam so I am deleting it. This type of question is
>   unacceptable at this site, anyways.

I just want to say that it is not a spam. I do not own Dailymotion.com, YouTube greatest competitor, to spam for it.

Also, according to the moderator this [question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/72037/is-dailymotion-cloud-expensive-compared-to-others) is unacceptable. The thing is saying *unacceptable* is vague. What do you mean by unacceptable?

- Is it off-topic?
- Is it non-constructive?
- Is it a duplicate?
- And so on...

It seems also that the pricing tag [exists](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pricing) on this website with 7 questions asked already, for example this [one](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/54529/what-kind-of-website-can-be-run-on-aws-for-10-100-1-thousand-10-thousand-100).

I'd appreciate also if someone would tell how can I edit my question again and flag it for undeleting.

Comment: I'd have to agree with the answers here: for the most part it did resemble the kind of self-promotion we might see on the site, which is typically removed pretty quickly. Apart from the advertorial appearance, although it could seem reasonable to ask for an opinion or comparison of services, there's unfortunately no way for us to know the motives behind posts, so as a blanket policy we have to put those types of questions on hold, otherwise the quality and authenticity of information found here would become questionable (so don't take it personally).

Comment: I don't take it personally. I've had similar previous experiences on Stackexchange, and I don't usually take anything personal from moderators.

Comment: DMCLOUD.com doesn't even exist...

Comment: .net ***** typo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since I closed and deleted the question I'll offer more insight as to why I did so.

This question is unacceptable at Pro Webmasters due to it being opinion-based. Asking for opinions is obviously opinion-based and pricing questions almost always are opinion-based as well. If you look at the questions tagged with "pricing" there are only three. One was already closed, one should have been closed (and now is) and the other one probably should be closed. Just because a tag exists does *not* mean questions related to it are on-topic.

As for why I deleted it, your question very much reads like an advertisement. The amount of pricing information, and the format in which you posted it, was not necessary for the questions you asked. Unfortunately big companies like to spam just like little companies do so the fact that someone is a competitor to a big company does not exclude them from potentially using underhanded techniques to promote themselves (especially when trying to compete with a large competitor with a huge advantage over them). So all we have is content and user reputation to go on when evaluating a question. As a new user posting what looks like an advertisement it should be easy to see why it was seen as spammy and deleted.

As it stands, there is no way for you to reword this question to make it acceptable at this website. Asking for opinions on pricing just do not fit here. The best you can do at the Stack Exchange network of websites is ask this in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/524/webmasters). Chat is designed for discussion and does not have the same quality guidelines at the main site does. So opinion based questions are allowed and welcomed.

Answer (score 4):

#### Problem #1

It looks like spam to me too.  It promotes the product for several paragraphs before asking the question "is it true?"    Posts designed to promote a product are not allowed.

#### Problem #2

It is asking for opinions.   "What do you think?"  is a red flag for me.   Answers here are expected to be based on facts, evidence, and experience.   Asking what people "think" about something doesn't fit in with the quality we expect on this site.

#### Problem #3

It asking for comparisons with "Would that expensive compared to other competitors?"   Questions that ask for answers to compare third party services don't work well with the moderation system here and are closed as off-topic

#### Problem #4

It's more than one question.  Because there are multiple questions contained in the post, I would close it as "too broad."