# Are questions about Azure pricing off-topic?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

I want to ask about pricing for an Azure MySql database. It looked at Micoroft's pricing information, but it is hard to understand.

**Is asking about pricing, especially on how the achieve the cheapest pricing for a specific service, on-topic here?**

Cody Gray for [I have a question about Windows Azure compute pricing and perhaps other compute pricing methods as well](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/12136/21106) says off-topic, is this the consensus here?

Comment: The best people to answer question about pricing are the ones who actually set the pricing (and do the charging). We may tell you one thing and then they may charge you something differently.

Answer (score 6):

It is common on all StackExchange sites that pricing questions are off-topic.  This includes questions regarding the relative, as opposed to absolute, prices of similar services.

Prices change and vary from country to country.  Such questions become obsolete quickly and are of interest to a limited number of visitors to the site.

I see no reason to treat Azure differently.

Answer (score 4):

Cody's comment on that question was posted when the question was still on StackOverflow, before it has been migrated here to Webmasters.   Pricing questions are indeed off-topic at SO: [Burninate pricing tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272482/burninate-pricing)  I couldn't find the specific reason behind it, but it appears that on-topic questions about coding rarely have pricing figure into it there.

Pricing is not specifically off-topic here.  We don't address pricing at all in our help center.  We have several meta discussions that touch on it:

- [Question deleted because moderator thinks it looks like a spam and it is unacceptable](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1280/question-deleted-because-moderator-thinks-it-looks-like-a-spam-and-it-is-unaccep): Opinions about pricing ("is this a good price", "which price should I choose", etc) are off topic as "Primarily opinion based"
- [Host Recommendation Questions - On Topic?](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187/host-recommendation-questions-on-topic): Mentions of a price in a recommendation question make it much less applicable to anybody else with a similar problem but maybe slightly differnt budget.   In any case, recommendation questions are now firmly off-topic here.

As a moderator here, I would not close a question about understanding web hosting pricing as off-topic.

In fact, I can think of a few similar questions:

- [Price of Amazon CloudFront vs dedicated server?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/36011/price-of-amazon-cloudfront-vs-dedicated-server)
- [Cloud hosting vs self hosting price](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35184/cloud-hosting-vs-self-hosting-price)
- [What kind of website can be run on AWS for 10, 100, 1 thousand, 10 thousand, 100 thousand, 1 million dollars per month?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/54529/what-kind-of-website-can-be-run-on-aws-for-10-100-1-thousand-10-thousand-100)
- [How do “tiered price” domains work?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/121165/how-do-tiered-price-domains-work)

Comment: I'd agree with this too. Questions that are primarily asking for help understanding pricing models don't necessarily hinge on the specific pricing itself (which would otherwise get outdated and invite price comparisons or self-promotional answers/comments). I think this is one of those gray areas that we should keep in mind, and possibly try to edge the question to be in alignment with (by editing if possible) so that it doesn't end up closed just because it mentions pricing.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer. I felt encouraged and have put up my question here: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/125712/cheapest-way-to-use-a-mysql-database-on-microsoft-azure I tried to focus more on the way to run the server than on the actual prices.